# Save changes in existing Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

My code creates and fills data in an Excel file. The problem is, when i want to make some changes and add more info it tells that file already exist. I know that the problem is in this part, because code saves as a new file and tells that file with this name already exist. Any ideas? **CODE UPDATED!**

```
try
            {
                Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
                app.DisplayAlerts = false;

                if (File.Exists("C:\\Users\\Adil Aliyev\\Documents\\log.xlsx")) { ObjWorkBook.Save(); MessageBox.Show("Saved"); }
                else
                {
                    ObjWorkBook.SaveAs("log.xlsx", Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                    MessageBox.Show("created");
                }

                ObjWorkBook.Close();
                app.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
            }
```

Comment: if all else fails, remove existing file and then do the save

Comment: @John, when i use Save - syntax error appears

Comment: can you please give an example? @John

Comment: didn't work. updated question

Answer (score 0):

The integral code I used to make it work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Excel_Save_Over_Existing_File
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Excel.Application oApp;
       Excel.Workbook oBook;
       Excel.Worksheet oSheet;

       oApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

       string fileTest = "C:\\Users\\Adil Aliyev\\Documents\\log.xlsx";
        if (File.Exists(fileTest))
        {
            File.Delete(fileTest);
        }

            oApp = new Excel.Application();
            oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
            oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "1";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "0";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "0";
            oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "1";

            oBook.SaveAs(fileTest);
            oBook.Close();
            oApp.Quit();

    }
}
}
```

Note that I used your path in order to make it easier for you to understand. The values I added in the Excel file are just for me to test, instead of those `oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "1";` lines you have to insert the code that creates the data you want to save in the Excel file. 
This works like a charm for me, hope it will work for you too. Have a nice day! (:

Comment: Did not help, sir. Still a message box with ("File already exist, would you like to replace it?")...

Comment: Without the changes I mentioned above, try putting this before the SaveAs line: System.IO.File.Delete(fileName); (where fileName is the path of the old Excel file)

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't help

Comment: Will try to make a project on my own a little later and will come back with a tested solution, right now I can only give you instructions without trying anything myself...

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir

Comment: I have edited my original answer so that it is easier to understand what you have to do, hope it helps!